# Sitecore freezes when trying to define WFFM (Web Forms For Marketers) restricted placeholders

Tags: sitecore

I have the latest version of WFMM (Web Forms For Marketers) for Sitecore. When I try to define the restricted placeholders from Desktop -> All Applications -> Web Forms for Maketers -> Restricted Placeholders everything freezes, including IIS.

I have no errors in the browser console or Sitecore's log.txt.

Answer (score 2):

I has same issue with Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150621 (Update-4) and  Web Forms for Marketers 8.0 rev. 150625. Sitecore Support helped me:

> The `//*[contains(@Allowed Controls, '{0}')]` query runs on all items from the database. We apologize for any inconvenience this issue may have caused.
>
> I changed the query to search items only under the root item: `.//*[contains(@Allowed Controls, '{0}')]`
>
> Could you please follow the steps below to address the issue:
>
> 1. Copy the attached `Sitecore.Support.406505.dll` assembly to /bin folder.
> 2. Change the implementation class for `forms:selectplaceholders` command in `forms.config` file:
>
> from
>
> `<command name="forms:selectplaceholders" type="Sitecore.Forms.Core.Commands.RestrinctingPlaceholders,Sitecore.Forms.Core" />`
>
> to
>
> `<command name="forms:selectplaceholders" type="Sitecore.Support.Forms.Core.Commands.RestrinctingPlaceholders,Sitecore.Support.406505" />`

Here is the linked to the mentioned dll: [Sitecore.Support.406505.dll](https://www.skillcore.net/content/Sitecore.Support.406505.dll)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it's not freezing anymore, but I get the following error: Could not load type 'Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.Constants' from assembly 'Sitecore.Forms.Core, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: I has this problem with `Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150621 (Update-4)` and patch from Sitecore Support was prepared for this particular build. If you're using another version, you may need to contact with Support to get patch that will match your version.

Comment: I have Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160302 (Update-2)

Comment: Then I guess you have to contact with Sitecore Support to provide you with correct dll.

Comment: Or you can use some decompiler to get content of the linked dll and recompile it against your sitecore and WFFM versions.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting Placeholder dialog is an quick way to add WFFM sublayout form and view form to *Allowed Controls* field in placeholder settings. Selection of placeholders is maintained on last step of installation of module. Everything is already installed, you just need to follow manual poststeps(attach DB, etc). You can continue without solving this problem.

And if you don't have a huge amount of placeholders then it is quicker to do it using *Allowed Controls* field rather than trying to find root of the problem.